# PHP5.6 error gives when check the version

Tags: php, php-5.6

when check the version of PHP,

```
php -v
```

an error message gives

php: symbol lookup error: php: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_exec

Comment: Time to pass to 7.2 :P

Comment: This might be good enough reason for a re-installation or an upgrade. Seems like some files/bits are missing from your installation. `php -v` should work right out of the box.